# Does this trap have a name?

Tags: opening-traps

I can across this trap playing a bullet game and I wonder if it has a name:

```
    [FEN ""]

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Nf6 4.Nc3 Bc5 5.Nd5 Nxd5 6.Bxd5 Nd4 7. Ng5 O-O 8.Qh5 Nxc2+ 9.Kf1 h6 10.Nxf7 Kh7 11.Nxd8 Rxf2+
```

And now black has a checkmate in 3.

Comment: @IanBush ops, sorry about that.

Comment: @IanBush and thanks for corrections, i've checked they are ok

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pattern starting from `Nxf7` does not correspond to any known (opening) trap. It's to be expected as this does not really qualify as a trap for the following reasons:

1. The path up to the critical position `10.Nxf7` has major flaws, e.g. white is hanging a full knight on move `7.Ng5` (`7...Qxg5`), so objectively, white is already lost before any trap setup is reached. Therefore, this move order does not really belong to a branch of a known opening (here the Four Knights game: Italian var).
2. Opening traps usually occur when one side is baited/tempted towards a known losing variation, such as the [Légal Trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9gal_Trap). Sometimes the side attempting to set up a trap might have to make a non-optimal, nearly dubious move to force the desired variation, but (at least for most known traps) if the opponent spots the trap and plays a refutation the game remains about equal.

However, in your example, assuming black is indeed setting up a trap, white can [*] simply play `11.d4` instead of falling for `11.Nxd8,` and white's completely winning as both `dxc5` and `Bxh6` are threatened and they cannot be simultaneously parried, therefore, black is lost and if anything, all this has been nothing but a last attempted tactical bait in an otherwise completely lost position.

[*]: other than the fact that white can simply play `9.Kd1` instead of `Kf1` and be completely winning having also side-stepped black's combination along the `f`-file.